# ReactiveCocoa and MVVM confusion

Tags: ios, iphone, mvvm, reactive-cocoa

I am reading a article from raywenderlinch: http://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1

I noticed there are protocols in Model and ViewModel folder. There is RWTFlickrSearch protocol, and RWTViewModelServices protocol. All these protocols and models and view modes are really confusing. The author didn't explain why create these protocols. I just find it hard to understand. Can someone explain the logic here?

Answer (score 3):

article author here ;-)

Protocols are not directly related to ReactiveCocoa or MVVM. They are simply a way of defining an interface that can have multiple implementations. It is also a way to reduce coupling between the various layers and components of an application.

The `RWTFlickrSearch` is the protocol that defines the interface for the `Model` layer. There is only one implementation of this interface included, but during development I used this protocol in order to 'inject' a dummy implementation with test data.

The same is true with `RWTViewModelServices`, it means that the `ViewModel` layer is not tightly coupled to the other services.